# Python - writing raw SQL to manipulate dataframes in Python

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am trying to perform SQL-language functions on Python Dataframes as if they were tables in Microsoft SQL Server. Seraching around, it appears that R has the module sqldf, and Python has some record of compatibility with pandasql - however I am unable to get Rodeo to work, if that is a requirement.

[This Blog](https://mathewanalytics.com/2015/06/29/turning-data-into-awesome-with-sqldf-and-pandasql/) has records of the above. I am unable to import sqldf or pandasql by running any combination of

```
import pandasql as pdsql
from pandasql import sqldf
pysql = lambda q: pdsql.sqldf(q, globals())
which I scavenged from here and there.
```

In SAS, you are able to manipulate SAS datasets using PROC SQL as such:

```
PROC SQL;
    SELECT 
        b.patid,
        CASE WHEN ECD='1234' THEN 'ACTIVE' ELSE 'ACTIVE' END AS ACTIVE_INACTIVE,        
        b.SUMMARY_ID
    FROM SAStable1 a
    LEFT JOIN SAStable2 b
        ON a.patient_id=b.patid
       ;
QUIT;
```

This results in being able to type a SQL query on SAS datasets in SAS. This is different than pandas.read_sql_query(query, connection) function, which works great on running SQL queries on connected databases, *but not in actual dataframes once they are in Python* (unless I am missing something).

Is there anything like this for Python? Given that its available in SAS and R, I would be surprised, but my searches yield nothing actionable.

Thanks!

Comment: did you install pandasql? what errors did you get?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need SQL to do this in pandas.
you can JOIN two dataframes using:

```
df1.set_index('patient_id').join(df2.set_index('patid'))
```

you can create a column based on a condition, similar to `CASE WHEN ECD='1234' THEN 'ACTIVE' ELSE 'ACTIVE' END AS ACTIVE_INACTIVE,`

by doing something like:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[100,1234],[101,1234],[102,4356]], columns=['patient_id','ECD'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[100,345],[101,23423],[102,3423]], columns=['patid','SUMMARY_ID'])
df3 = df1.set_index('patient_id').join(df2.set_index('patid'))

def active(row):
     if row['ECD'] == 1234 :
         return 'ACTIVE'
     else:
         return 'INACTIVE'

df3['ACTIVE_INACTIVE'] = df3.apply(active, axis=1))
```

If you really need to use SQL, you can install pandasql using

```
sudo -H pip3 install pandasql
```

you can then use it like you would expect:

```
from pandasql import sqldf
pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())
q = """SELECT
        *,
        CASE WHEN a.ECD='1234' THEN 'ACTIVE' ELSE 'INACTIVE' END AS ACTIVE_INACTIVE        
        FROM
        df1 a
      JOIN
        df2 b
           ON a.patient_id = b.patid;"""
print(pysqldf(q).head())
```

Answer (score 2):

As source codes show, both R's [sqldf](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf/blob/master/R/sqldf.R) and Python's [pandasql](https://github.com/yhat/pandasql/blob/master/pandasql/sqldf.py) actually run **in-memory** SQLite instances (SQLite by default for R). So really, you can replicate the functionality with pandas' SQL methods ([read_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) and [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)) by interfacing with [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/sqlite.html) which pandasql in fact does under the hood! Specifically, consider the following with demo example:

1. Import all needed environment dataframes into an in-memory SQLite database:

   ```
   import numpy as np
   import pandas as pd
   from sqlalchemy import create_engine

   # IN-MEMORY DATABASE (NO PATH SPECIFIED)
   engine = create_engine('sqlite://')

   dates = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-06-22', freq='D')
   df1 = pd.DataFrame({'current_date': np.random.choice(dates, 50),
                       'analysis_tool': 'pandas',                  
                       'num_value': np.random.randint(100, size=50)*1000                           
                      }, columns=['current_date', 'analysis_tool', 'num_value'])

   df2 = pd.DataFrame({'current_date': np.random.choice(dates, 50),
                       'analysis_tool': 'r',                  
                       'num_value': np.random.randint(100, size=50)*1000                           
                      }, columns=['current_date', 'analysis_tool', 'num_value'])

   df3 = pd.DataFrame({'current_date': np.random.choice(dates, 50),
                       'analysis_tool': 'sas',                  
                       'num_value': np.random.randint(100, size=50)*1000                           
                      }, columns=['current_date', 'analysis_tool', 'num_value'])

   df1.to_sql("df1", con=engine, if_exists='replace')
   df2.to_sql("df2", con=engine, if_exists='replace')
   df3.to_sql("df3", con=engine, if_exists='replace')
   ```
2. Run your needed SQL queries to update and manipulate data:

   ```
   # QUERIES RUN IN A TRANSACTION
   with engine.begin() as cn:
      cn.execute("UPDATE df1 SET analysis_tool = 'python pandas'")
      cn.execute("INSERT INTO df3 (analytic_tool, current_date, num_value) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", 
                 ('sas', '2018-06-23', 51000))
   ```
3. Import as a pandas dataframe:

   ```
   strSQL = """SELECT * FROM df1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT * FROM df2
               UNION ALL
               SELECT * FROM df3;"""

   df_all = pd.read_sql(strSQL, engine)

   engine.dispose()                       # IN-MEMORY DATABASE DESTROYED
   ```

Comment: thanks - i'm too new to understand this, but im not able to run part 2 as is

Comment: OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near ")": syntax error [SQL: "UPDATE df1 SET analysis_tool = 'python pandas')"] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

Comment: if i put the " outside the )) after 'python pandas' i get:  cn.execute("INSERT INTO df3 (analytic_tool, current_date, num_value) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax....     with the "^" pointing to cn

Comment: Whoops! There should not be any parenthesis inside the `UPDATE` statement raising the SQLite error. The second error is a  Python syntax error due to extra parenthesis that should be removed.

Comment: great! along with analytic_tool as analysis_tool. I'm not exactly sure how to use this. I was hoping for: for df1 and df2 which exist as dataframes in python as variables, do something like "select * from df1 where Patient_id not in df2". is that doable with this method?